# Loop not running

Tags: c

I trying to compare words from an file with user input.
Everything is done but 2nd Loop still not running? Any possibility to check?

Basically what I am trying to do is: like there is word 'my' in my text.file. Now I want to show it is a pronoun by comparing this text.txt file 'my' with the user input 'my' in his sentence.

Test.txt file:

> we
>   i
>   my
>   you

Trying to compare strings of test.txt file with the code one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FNAME "test.txt"    /* if you need constants, define them */
#define NOUN "nouns.txt"
#define VERB "verbs.txt"
#define TENC   10
#define MAXC  100

int main (void) {

    int c = 0, i = 0, ndx = 0,          /* misc. counters & index    */
        fwords = 0,                     /* number of words in file   */
        uwords = 0;                     /* number of words from user */
    char arr[MAXC] = "",                /* storage for file contents */
        str1[MAXC] = "",                /* storage for user string   */
        wordsfile[TENC][TENC] = { "" }, /* separated words from file */
        wordsnoun[TENC][TENC] = { "" },
        wordsverb[TENC][TENC] = { "" },
        wordsuser[TENC][TENC] = { "" }; /* separated words from user */

        //wordsnoun[] = { "dog", "fleas" };  /* nouns - example       */

    size_t len = 0,                     /* string length             */
        nnouns = sizeof wordsnoun / sizeof *wordsnoun,
        nverbs = sizeof wordsverb / sizeof *wordsverb;  /* no. nouns */


    FILE *fp = fopen (FNAME, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {       /* validate file open for reading */
        perror (FNAME);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n Reading from '%s' and separating into words by line :\n"
            " --------------------------------------------------------\n\n",
            FNAME);

    /* read characters from file into 'arr' and separate into words
     * by newline into 'wordsfile'. nul-terminate each word. protect
     * all array bounds and against non-POSIX eof.
     */
    while (ndx < MAXC && fwords < TENC && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {    /* separate words in file by line */
            wordsfile[fwords++][i] = 0;    /* nul-terminate */
            i = 0;          /* reset words character count */
        }
        else  /* assign char to both wordsfile & arr */
            wordsfile[fwords][i++] = arr[ndx++] = c;

        if (i >= TENC) {    /* protect array bounds */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: wordsfile - word too long.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (i)  /* handle non-POSIX file ending (no '\n') */
        wordsfile[fwords++][i] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */

    fclose (fp);    /* close the file - done with it */


    FILE *np = fopen (NOUN, "r");

    if (np == NULL) {       /* validate file open for reading */
        perror (NOUN);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n Reading from '%s' and separating into words by line :\n"
            " --------------------------------------------------------\n\n",
            NOUN);

    /* read characters from file into 'arr' and separate into words
     * by newline into 'wordsfile'. nul-terminate each word. protect
     * all array bounds and against non-POSIX eof.
     */
    while (ndx < MAXC && fwords < TENC && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {    /* separate words in file by line */
            wordsnoun[fwords++][i] = 0;    /* nul-terminate */
            i = 0;          /* reset words character count */
        }
        else  /* assign char to both wordsfile & arr */
            wordsnoun[fwords][i++] = arr[ndx++] = c;

        if (i >= TENC) {    /* protect array bounds */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: wordsnoun - word too long.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (i)  /* handle non-POSIX file ending (no '\n') */
        wordsnoun[fwords++][i] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */

    fclose (np);    /* close the file - done with it */




    FILE *vp = fopen (VERB, "r");

    if (vp == NULL) {       /* validate file open for reading */
        perror (VERB);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n Reading from '%s' and separating into words by line :\n"
            " --------------------------------------------------------\n\n",
            VERB);

    /* read characters from file into 'arr' and separate into words
     * by newline into 'wordsfile'. nul-terminate each word. protect
     * all array bounds and against non-POSIX eof.
     */
    while (ndx < MAXC && fwords < TENC && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {    /* separate words in file by line */
            wordsverb[fwords++][i] = 0;    /* nul-terminate */
            i = 0;          /* reset words character count */
        }
        else  /* assign char to both wordsfile & arr */
            wordsverb[fwords][i++] = arr[ndx++] = c;

        if (i >= TENC) {    /* protect array bounds */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: wordsverb - word too long.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (i)  /* handle non-POSIX file ending (no '\n') */
        wordsverb[fwords++][i] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */

    fclose (vp);    /* close the file - done with it */




    for (i = 0; i < fwords; i++) /* output words from file */
        printf ("wordsfile[%d] : %s\n", i, wordsnoun[i]);

    printf ("\n Split string by space into words :\n"
            " --------------------------------------\n"
            " Input  a string : ");    

    if (fgets (str1, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {    /* validate input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    len = strlen (str1);    /* validate string length */
    if (len + 1 == MAXC && str1[len - 1] != '\n') {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: string too long.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* separate str1 into words on space ' '.
     * this is the same approach as used on wordsfile.
     * (note: you can use strtok for this purpose) 
     */
    for (i = 0, c = 0; c < (int)len; c++) {
        if (str1[c] == ' ' || str1[c] == '\n') {
            wordsuser[uwords++][i] = 0;
            i = 0;
        }
        else    /* assign char to wordsuser */
            wordsuser[uwords][i++] = str1[c];

        if (i >= TENC) {    /* protect array bounds */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: wordsuser - word too long.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (i)  /* handle last word in string */
        wordsuser[uwords++][i] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */

    putchar ('\n');
    for (i = 0; i < uwords; i++) /* output words from file */
        printf ("wordsuser[%d] : %s\n", i, wordsuser[i]);

    printf ("\n Determine if words entered by user are pronouns :\n"
            " ---------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    /* cycle through each word in user input comparing to words from file.
     * if match found, output words as pronoun, otherwise output as
     * not a pronoun.
     */
 for (i = 0; i < uwords; i++) {      /* for each word in wordsuser */
        printf (" %-10s - ", wordsuser[i]); /* output the word */
        for (c = 0; c < fwords; c++) {  /* for each word in wordsfile */
            /* do they match any word in wordsfile (pronouns) ? */
            if (strcmp (wordsuser[i], wordsfile[c]) == 0) {
                printf ("pronoun.\n");
                goto nextword;
            }
        }
        for (c = 0; c < (int)nnouns; c++)   /* do they match a noun? */
            if (strcmp (wordsuser[i], wordsnoun[c]) == 0) {
                printf ("noun.\n");
                goto nextword;
            }

        for (c = 0; c < (int)nverbs; c++)   /* do they match a noun? */
            if (strcmp (wordsuser[i], wordsverb[c]) == 0) {
                printf ("verb.\n");
                goto nextword;
            }
        /*
         *  ALL your remaining tests go here!
         */
        printf ("unclassified.\n");
        nextword:;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Don't' post images of 'text''. Properly include the 'text' itself as part of the question. Four lines totaling `we`, `I`, `my`, `you` is not too much to post. What happens if `char c = fgetc(f);` reaches `EOF`?? Can `EOF` be represented by `char`? What does `man 3 fgetc` tell you the return `type` of `fgetc` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question is a little hindered by its phrasing.

Where to begin? Let me give you my best understanding of what you are trying to accomplish based on the code above and your data file. If I'm not mistaken, you want to read the four words (pronouns) from the file `"test.txt"` and then separate the words on each line so that you can compare them against words entered by the user to determine if the words entered by the user are pronouns. Close?

While `strtok` is normally used to *tokenize* a sting into separate words, there is absolutely nothing wrong with tokeninzing the string manually by working your way from the beginning of a string (or file) to the end checking each character along the way and taking the needed actions to store the words separately. You can either use a pointer to walk down the string, or use string-indexing to accomplish the same thing.

While you could have simply read each line from `"test.txt"` into separate storage with repeated calls to `fgets` (and trimmed the trailing `'\n'` from each), there is nothing wrong with reading the file into a buffer and then parsing it. (Just as with any array or memory storage, it is ***up to you*** to make sure you do not try and store more characters than you have space for). So ***validate***. That also applies to using any function that has a return to indicate success or failure. Validate the return.

When working with any of the functions in `string.h`, they expect a *nul-terminated* string as input (e.g. `strlen`, `strcmp`, etc.). When you are reading character-by-character, it is **up to you** to make sure you affirmatively *nul-terminate* each array of characters you intend to use as a string, by insuring the final character is the *nul-character* (e.g. `'\0'` or just '0' -- they are equivalent, the *nul-character* has ASCII value `0`).

You can insure each of your strings are *nul-terminated* by assigning the *nul-character* as the final terminating character each time you fill the array -- or -- if you only write characters to the array once -- by careful initialization of your arrays to all `0` and by insuring you write no more than one less than the total number of characters to the array.

Think about the variables you will need beforehand. If you will have a number of words from a file and a number of words from the user, then `fwords` and `uwords` (or `fcount` and `ucount`) make sense. Likewise the 2D arrays for storage of the words from file and words from user can be `wordsfile` and `wordsuser` (or whatever name you like that bares some rational relationship to what you are storing).

While C99 and later no longer require all variables to be declared at the beginning of each code block, sometimes that isn't a bad practice to help you collect your thoughts and prevent the proliferation of unneeded and unrelated variables from growing throughout your code.

While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. Your `newString` has been renamed `wordsuser` below.

If you need constants in your code (array bounds, default filenames, etc.), then define them at the top of your source file. That way if any adjustment or change is needed, you have a single convenient location to make changes without having to pick through each line of your code.

Lastly, lay your code out logically. If you are opening a file, reading from it, and then separating the words in the file into separate storage, then do that in one section of your file. Don't do one it intermixed hither-thither throughout your code. Then `fclose` your file -- you are done with it.

The following is a guess at what you were intending with the above cleanups and tweaks applied. Note, there are shorter ways to approaching this, but attempt was made to keep the operations consistent with what it looked like you were attempting to do. Go through the code and make sure you understand why what was done -- was done. If you have questions, ask.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FNAME "test.txt"    /* if you need constants, define them */
#define TENC   10
#define MAXC  100

int main (void) {

    int c = 0, i = 0, ndx = 0,          /* misc. counters & index    */
        fwords = 0,                     /* number of words in file   */
        uwords = 0;                     /* number of words from user */
    size_t len = 0;                     /* string length             */
    char arr[MAXC] = "",                /* storage for file contents */
        str1[MAXC] = "",                /* storage for user string   */
        wordsfile[TENC][TENC] = { "" }, /* separated words from file */
        wordsuser[TENC][TENC] = { "" }; /* separated words from user */
    FILE *fp = fopen (FNAME, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {       /* validate file open for reading */
        perror (FNAME);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n Reading from '%s' and separating into words by line :\n"
            " --------------------------------------------------------\n\n",
            FNAME);

    /* read characters from file into 'arr' and separate into words
     * by newline into 'wordsfile'. nul-terminate each word. protect
     * all array bounds and against non-POSIX eof.
     */
    while (ndx < MAXC && fwords < TENC && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {    /* separate words in file by line */
            wordsfile[fwords++][i] = 0;    /* nul-terminate */
            i = 0;          /* reset words character count */
        }
        else  /* assign char to both wordsfile & arr */
            wordsfile[fwords][i++] = arr[ndx++] = c;

        if (i >= TENC) {    /* protect array bounds */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: wordsfile - word too long.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (i)  /* handle non-POSIX file ending (no '\n') */
        wordsfile[fwords++][i] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */

    fclose (fp);    /* close the file - done with it */

    for (i = 0; i < fwords; i++) /* output words from file */
        printf ("wordsfile[%d] : %s\n", i, wordsfile[i]);

    printf ("\n Split string by space into words :\n"
            " --------------------------------------\n"
            " Input  a string : ");    

    if (fgets (str1, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {    /* validate input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    len = strlen (str1);    /* validate string length */
    if (len + 1 == MAXC && str1[len - 1] != '\n') {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: string too long.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* separate str1 into words on space ' '.
     * this is the same approach as used on wordsfile.
     * (note: you can use strtok for this purpose) 
     */
    for (i = 0, c = 0; c < (int)len; c++) {
        if (str1[c] == ' ' || str1[c] == '\n') {
            wordsuser[uwords++][i] = 0;
            i = 0;
        }
        else    /* assign char to wordsuser */
            wordsuser[uwords][i++] = str1[c];

        if (i >= TENC) {    /* protect array bounds */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: wordsuser - word too long.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (i)  /* handle last word in string */
        wordsuser[uwords++][i] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */

    putchar ('\n');
    for (i = 0; i < uwords; i++) /* output words from file */
        printf ("wordsuser[%d] : %s\n", i, wordsuser[i]);

    printf ("\n Determine if words entered by user are pronouns :\n"
            " ---------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    /* cycle through each word in user input comparing to words from file.
     * if match found, output words as pronoun, otherwise output as
     * not a pronoun.
     */
    for (i = 0; i < uwords; i++) {      /* for each word in wordsuser */
        int pronoun = 0;                /* flag for pronoun found */
        for (c = 0; c < fwords; c++) {  /* for each word in wordsfile */
            /* do they match ? */
            if (strcmp (wordsuser[i], wordsfile[c]) == 0) {
                printf (" %-10s - pronoun.\n", wordsuser[i]);
                pronoun = 1;
            }
        }
        if (!pronoun)   /* if no match found */
            printf (" %-10s - not a pronoun.\n", wordsuser[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** additional error checks and error handling can and should be added to your code, the above was just minimal to protect array bounds)

**Example Use/Output**

The following is a short example using your `"test.txt"` file and miscellaneous string that will exercise the pronoun check.

```
$ ./bin/splitonspace

 Reading from 'test.txt' and separating into words by line :
 --------------------------------------------------------

wordsfile[0] : we
wordsfile[1] : I
wordsfile[2] : my
wordsfile[3] : you

 Split string by space into words :
 --------------------------------------
 Input  a string : I don't want my dog to have fleas do you

wordsuser[0] : I
wordsuser[1] : don't
wordsuser[2] : want
wordsuser[3] : my
wordsuser[4] : dog
wordsuser[5] : to
wordsuser[6] : have
wordsuser[7] : fleas
wordsuser[8] : do
wordsuser[9] : you

 Determine if words entered by user are pronouns :
 ---------------------------------------------------

 I          - pronoun.
 don't      - not a pronoun.
 want       - not a pronoun.
 my         - pronoun.
 dog        - not a pronoun.
 to         - not a pronoun.
 have       - not a pronoun.
 fleas      - not a pronoun.
 do         - not a pronoun.
 you        - pronoun.
```

---

**Example of Adding Additional Tests for "nouns", etc.**

As explained in the comments, all the basic tools (to do any number of checks) were provided in my original answer above. Adding additional checks just means:

1. reading the words for additional classifications from another file (or source);
2. storing those words in another array (or suitable storage) and knowing how many of each type word you have; and finally
3. adding a comparison for the new type to the loop where you loop over all the words supplied by the user at the end - checking against the new list of words you have.

To prevent just duplicating another file read for purposes of this example, I've just added an array of pointers to the *nouns* `"dog"` and `"fleas"` and changed the default message from `"not a pronoun"` to `"unclassified"` if a word is neither a *noun* or *pronoun*. To provide simple storage for the comparison nouns, I added a `wordsnoun` array (of pointers to string literals -- you will fill a normal 2D array from a file, just like was done for `wordsfile` above). For this example I added:

```
    char arr[MAXC] = "",                /* storage for file contents */
    ...
        *wordsnoun[] = { "dog", "fleas" };  /* nouns - example       */
    size_t len = 0,                     /* string length             */
        nnouns = sizeof wordsnoun / sizeof *wordsnoun;  /* no. nouns */
```

Where the *number of nouns* is held in `nnouns`. (also **note:** I move the declaration for `len` below the character array declarations to account for `nnouns` along with `len`)

Then it is just a matter of adding a check against each of the words in `wordsnoun` as you loop over each word entered by the user. (I also added a `goto` to prevent unneeded comparisons after a match has occurred). Example:

```
    /* cycle through each word in user input comparing to classification words.
     * if match found, output classification for word, otherwise if no match
     * is found, output "unclassified".
     */
    for (i = 0; i < uwords; i++) {      /* for each word in wordsuser */
        printf (" %-10s - ", wordsuser[i]); /* output the word */
        for (c = 0; c < fwords; c++) {  /* for each word in wordsfile */
            /* do they match any word in wordsfile (pronouns) ? */
            if (strcmp (wordsuser[i], wordsfile[c]) == 0) {
                printf ("pronoun.\n");
                goto nextword;
            }
        }
        for (c = 0; c < (int)nnouns; c++)   /* do they match a noun? */
            if (strcmp (wordsuser[i], wordsnoun[c]) == 0) {
                printf ("noun.\n");
                goto nextword;
            }
        /*
         *  ALL your remaining tests go here!
         */
        printf ("unclassified.\n");
        nextword:;
    }
```

**Example Use/Output**

Making those changes would result in the following output:

```
$ ./bin/splitonspace

 Reading from 'test.txt' and separating into words by line :
 --------------------------------------------------------

wordsfile[0] : we
wordsfile[1] : I
wordsfile[2] : my
wordsfile[3] : you

 Split string by space into words :
 --------------------------------------
 Input a string : I don't want my dog to have fleas do you
 String entered : I don't want my dog to have fleas do you

wordsuser[0] : I
wordsuser[1] : don't
wordsuser[2] : want
wordsuser[3] : my
wordsuser[4] : dog
wordsuser[5] : to
wordsuser[6] : have
wordsuser[7] : fleas
wordsuser[8] : do
wordsuser[9] : you

 Determine if words entered by user are pronouns :
 ---------------------------------------------------

 I          - pronoun.
 don't      - unclassified.
 want       - unclassified.
 my         - pronoun.
 dog        - noun.
 to         - unclassified.
 have       - unclassified.
 fleas      - noun.
 do         - unclassified.
 you        - pronoun.
```

There is no magic to adding even more different types of classifications, from as many other word types as you like. Just follow steps `1, 2 & 3` for each new classifications of words you add. (and remember to adjust your constants and array sizes as required) Good luck.

Comment: Thankyou so much Sir :)

Comment: Sir can you edit this code like I can access All parts of Speech; like connecting 7 Text Files and in Output; instead of saying Not a Pronoun; I can show it is Noun or something else.

Comment: Sure, we can do anything that it needed, but what do you mean by "connecting 7 Text Files and in Output"? In your code you had `ki`. are you talking about stripping the spaces from the user input to make one long string without spaces?

Comment: No Sir, I have attached one ".txt" which contains all Pronouns. I want to attach 8 more ".txt" files which will contain noun, verb, adjective, adverb, conjunction, interjection, preposition and article respectively.
Therefore in the Output Instead of saying "Not a Pronoun" I want to show that it is a noun, verb, adjective etc.

Comment: I got you. Still, not a problem. You need a way to specify all the filenames to read from. You can essentially just do the same read we did for `wordsfile` seven more times filling seven additional arrays (e.g. `nouns`, `adverbs`, `prepositions`, etc... You would then need to add the seven additional tests inside `for (i = 0; i < uwords; i++)`. There are more elegant ways of handling this, but let's start with the basics first. Give that a try. If you get stuck, post the contents of some or all of the other files `nouns`, etc. and I'll help further.

Comment: ` for(int i=1; i<=7;i++) {
    switch(i){
                case 1:{
                     findWords(FNAME,"pronoun");
                     break;
                     }    
                    
                      case 2:{
                     findWords(noun"noun");
                     break;
                     } `

Comment: Contents of Noun Files:
tree
apple
banana

Contents of Verb File:
is
were
applies

Comment: You essentially have to read the 7 files sequentially, separate each line into a string in your new array (say `wordsnoun`.. repeat for all others). Then inside your `for (i = 0; i < uwords; i++)` loop you would set a simple flag like `int categorized = 0;` Then with each check (e.g. is is a `pronoun`?, is it a `noun`?, etc.. if it matches, output the indication you want and set `categorized = 1;`. After all checks (`pronoun, noun, ...`) if you still haven't matched, output something like `" - uncategorized"` and go check the next word.

Comment: For your checks, remember you are still only looping over `for (i = 0; i < uwords; i++)` -- `uwords` and `wordsuser` didn't change, you are just checking for `noun`, etc.. **in addition to** your check for `pronoun` in that same loop.

Comment: Sir Kindly see my question code. I have modified it for both pronouns and nouns but still it is showing many things are undeclared. Couldn't resolve why it is saying that

Comment: The approach shows promise, but you must provide a forward declaration for `int findWords(name,partOfspeech)` (and any other function), before they are called in `main`. Before we go further. I want you to compile with **warnings enabled**, e.g. add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your compiler options if using `gcc`, add `-Weverything` if using clang, or add `/W3` if using VS (e.g. `cl.exe`) and don't except code until it compiles without warning. Give it a go and let me know when you have eliminated the compiler warning.

Comment: Sir now Compiler is showing *no warnings*. But still things aren't working. Kindly have a look onto my code.

Comment: Sir can you edit your last answer code and instead of only for pronoun; modify it to attach 8 more ".txt" files which will contain noun, verb, adjective, adverb, toconjunction, interjection, preposition and article respectively

Comment: I'll add to it, but it will be tomorrow before I can add examples for multiple checks.

Comment: Thankyou Sir.  I will be even more thankful if you do it after 5-6 hours. It's 3 33 PM here so I am trying to complete this till night. 
May God be Pleased upon you :)

Comment: Sir I have modified the code inside the question. Sir Two problems are still occurring:
1. Pronouns and Verb words are not being displayed
2. Verb is not functional inside the loop
Kindly resolve this issue

Comment: Sir! Can you resolve this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283763/compilation-errors-not-allowing-to-run-the-program